# Two Sites, One Firewall, Two wireless bridge, One ADSL modem,Internet Sharing

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, firewall

I have two physically separate sites, Site A and Site B.

- Site A - connected two Side B via a Wireless Bridge
- Site A - Transparent Wireless bridge terminates into the switch of Site A
- Site A - Has a managed switch and a Firewall acting as a DHCP server
- Site A - Firewall has multiple configurable Wan ports to any configuration
- Site A - Firewall already has a internet connection configured for a WAN port
- Site A - Firewall has a port configured as a LAN Port and connected to the      switch
- Site B - Transparent Wireless bridge switch directly terminates into the switch
- Site B - Services all DHCP clients request from Firewall at Site A
- Site B - Is on the same subnet as site A

Now The question is I have installed a new ADSL modem at Site B and need to feed it in the firewall at Site A. How can it be done

Note - The new modem can be configured as a bridge as the ISP has provided with a static ip for the connection which can be easily configure at the desired port of the firewall at site A. Also the Existing ADSL connection at Site A is connected to the firewall via a direct Ethernet cable and the modem is configured in bridge mode.

Network Map:

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific with what kind of hardware you are dealing with or add a network map?

Comment: Hi, Sorry I do not have a network map at the moment. The Hardware details are -- Site A - Firewall;Cyberoam CR35ing , Switch; Cisco SG300 , Wireless Bridge; Ubiquiti power beam M5 --- Site B - Wireless Bridge; Ubiquiti power beam M5, Switch; Cisco SG300 Note - I Have given the detail in the same order the devices are connected with the Ethernet cable. Regards

Comment: Hi, This is the Network Map you asked  for                                                                                                                ![<div="Network Diagram">hover me</div>]
(http://i.imgur.com/qWceHWv.png)

Comment: Hi, still waiting on a reply